# How to customize bootstrap 4 using angular-cli

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, twitter, angular-cli, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have an Angular 4 application using angular-cli 1.0 and Bootstrap 4-alpha6.
I want to customize Bootstrap 4. E.g. change the color of the primary buttons.

It must be a future proof solution. That means my customizations must survive upgrades of bootstrap at a later point in time.

I have integrated bootstrap by: 
Adding  `"bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.6",` to the dependencies in my package.json file.
Furthermore I added

```
"styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      ],
```

to `"apps"` in angular-cli.json.

My first try was to create a new file called style.scss, put it into src/assets and also reference it in angular-cli.json.

The content could look like this:

```
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";

$body-bg:    $gray-dark;
$body-color: $gray-light;
```

When running `ng serve` the application comiles fine but I do not see any changes.

Did I even start in the right direction? How would I properly customize bootstrap buttons/styles via sass in a clean angular-cli workflow?

You can find the source here: https://github.com/nemoo/democratizer-angular/tree/ngbootstrap/frontend-angular

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The values you're attempting to change `$body-bg` & `$body-color` are SASS values, not CSS values.

So you will need to reference the SASS files not the CSS file.

Update the default style file from `styles.css` to `styles.scss` and in that file...

```
// set the variables you wish to change
$body-bg:    $gray-dark;
$body-color: $gray-light;
// import in the bootstrap SASS file
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap'
```

You can read more [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-include-bootstrap#using-sass).

Comment: Note you can now also e.g.  `@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap'`